# free shipping and pickup store in opencart 3.0.2

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I am using opencart 3.0.2 and I want set up two pickup stores so customer can choose where pickup goods
...and In "Extentions > Free Shipping" can only choose one geo zone, but I wish to choose multiple geozones.
So what files I have to edit in opencart [https://github.com/opencart/opencart/tree/master/upload] and what kind of modifications to do?

thanks

Comment: instead of editing `opencart` core why not try to use `ocmod` or `vqmod` instead. Will be better to avoid editing the core files, otherwise upgrading to future versions will be a tedious task for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own geozone that contains many countries.
Here you can see an example : 
http://docs.opencart.com/system/localisation/geo-zone/